# Comparing index values in an array and returning a new array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm pretty new to programming and this is my first post.

I'm trying to create a method that takes an array (from a text file), compares the values in the sequence to find the longest nondecreasing sequence (**values** not index).

For example, in the array [2 3 4 1 50 2 3 3 4 5 1 4 ]    ***2 3 3 4 5*** should be returned (not **5**).

I've been trying to follow this article [Longest Increasing Sequence](https://forum.tutorials7.com/1506/longest-increasing-sequence-java-task)  but it uses ArrayLists (which I'm not allowed to use per the assignment)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public double brightSequenceNonDec()throws FileNotFoundException{

    double[] numbersInSequence = new double[numbersOfLines];
    for (int i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
        for (int k = i + 1; k < listElements.length; k++) {
            if (listElements[i].brightness()<=listElements[k].brightness()) {
                numbersInSequence[0] = listElements[i].brightness();

            }
        }
    }
```

Any direction as to what I'm doing incorrectly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an assignment, I won't spell out the full answer to you but provide some pointers.

It may be a good idea to divide your problem into sub problems. This will also make it easier to follow what's going on.

- Make a helper method that takes a start index as parameter and that returns the number of non-decreasing values from that index onward.
- Declare two local variables, one that stores the start index and one that stores the length of the longest sequence that you found thus far.
- In your loop, go through each index and use your helper method to check the length of the sequence starting at that index. If it's longer than your currently stored length, remember that index and the length as new best pick.

Once your loop finished, you can use [System.arraycopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) (or your own loop, if that's forbidden) to copy all values from the longest sequence into a new array. After all, you now know the starting point of the longest sequence and you know how long that sequence is. Which means you even know the initial size of your destination array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LongestIncreasingSequence {

double[] longestSequence(double input[]) {

    // variable start and end will store the starting index and ending index
    // of array
    // variable max will store the length of sequence and compare it to the
    // older length
    // length will store the maximum length
    int start = 0, end = 0, length = 0, index, max = 0;
    int arrayLength = input.length;

    for (index = 1; index < arrayLength; index++) {
        if (input[index] >= input[index - 1]) {
            max++;
        }

        else {
            if (max > length) {
                length = max;
                end = index;
                start = end - length - 1;
            }
            max = 0;
        }
    }

    // this condition will work when the last element is also the part of
    // the longest sequence
    if (max > length) {
        length = max;
        end = index;
        start = end - length - 1;
    }

    int resultLength = end - start;

    double result[] = new double[resultLength];

    for (index = 0; index < resultLength; index++, start++) {
        result[index] = input[start];
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

here you have:

```
public static int[] longestNonDecreasingSequence(int[] fullSequence) {
    int[] maxSequence = new int[0];
    int[] tmpSequence = new int[fullSequence.length];
    int tmpSequenceLength = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<fullSequence.length;i++) {
        if (i==0 || fullSequence[i] >= fullSequence[i-1]) {
            tmpSequence[tmpSequenceLength] = fullSequence[i];
            tmpSequenceLength++;
        } else {
            if (tmpSequenceLength>maxSequence.length) {
                maxSequence = new int[tmpSequenceLength];
                System.arraycopy(tmpSequence,0,maxSequence,0,maxSequence.length);
            }
            tmpSequence[0] = fullSequence[i];
            tmpSequenceLength=1;
        }
    }
     return maxSequence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply loop through the list of numbers twice. First to find how long the longest sequence is, then to find the longest sequence. This should do the trick:

```
    int[] nums = new int[] {2, 3, 4, 1, 50, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4};
    int prevNum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int longest = 0;
    int seq = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] >= prevNum) {
            seq += 1;
            if(seq > longest) {
                longest = seq;
            }
        } else {
            seq = 0;
        }
        prevNum = nums[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Longest: " + index);

    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] >= prevNum) {
            seq += 1;
            if(seq == longest) {
                index = i - longest;
                longest = seq;
            }
        } else {
            seq = 0;
        }
        prevNum = nums[i];
    }

    int[] longestSequenceValues = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, index, index + longest + 1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(longestSequenceValues));
    // Output: [2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```